# Service Reference in Xamarin.Android issue

Tags: android, wcf, xamarin, soap

I'm trying to develop a Xamarin App (Xam 4.7.10.38 with Xam.And.SDK 8.0.2.1 using PCL approach) connected to an Dynamics 365 Finance And Operation Custom Web Service.
Just to sum it up, it's a WCF Soap service that uses Azure Active Directory Client Id + Client Secret to connect to the soap service.

I've posted the most important part of the code below for reference.

So as instructed, I used the Silverlight SDK to create the service reference proxy class and also added the necessary framework references.
Then I included this proxy class in my Android Project as wel as in a standard .Net Windows App, both using VS.Net 2017.

Everything is identical up until I call `var resultAsync = service.BeginValidateUser(validateUserRequest, null, null);`

In my Windows App, it returns

> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.

I do the WaitOne to conclude it and my EndValidateUser returns a correct result.

However in my Android App, it returns

> System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult

which is a different object with different members/methods.
The Waitone still works, but when I call the EndValidateUser, I got an exception saying

> "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values.\nParameter name: value\n  at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native)
>   System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_end_invoke
>   (object,intptr)\n  at (wrapper delegate-end-invoke)
>   :end_invoke_object__this___object[]&_IAsyncResult
>   (object[]&,System.IAsyncResult)\n  at
>   System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.EndProcess
>   (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName,
>   System.Object[] parameters, System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0001f] in
>   <475dec2c1fe44b95bbfbd21b550b63f8>:0 \n  at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1+ChannelBase`1[TChannel,T].EndInvoke
>   (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args, System.IAsyncResult
>   result) [0x00045] in <475dec2c1fe44b95bbfbd21b550b63f8>:0 \n

Any idea's or approaches on how to solve this ?

Regards,
Sven Peeters

Code for Reference :

```
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Static_Functions.activeDirectoryTenant);

        string aadClientAppSecret = Static_Functions.activeDirectoryClientAppSecret;
        ClientCredential creadential = new ClientCredential(Static_Functions.activeDirectoryClientAppId, aadClientAppSecret);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Static_Functions.activeDirectoryResource, creadential).Result;
        string oAuthHeader = authenticationResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();

        string serviceName = "PWBMobilityServiceGroup";
        string soapServiceUriString = Static_Functions.GetSoapServiceUriString(serviceName, Static_Functions.aosUri);

        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(soapServiceUriString);
        System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding = Static_Functions.GetBinding();

        SchindlerTechAssist.Droid.D365Service.MobilityServiceClient client = new SchindlerTechAssist.Droid.D365Service.MobilityServiceClient(binding, endpointAddress);
        IClientChannel dimServiceChannel = client.InnerChannel;

        using (OperationContextScope dimServiceOperContext = new OperationContextScope(dimServiceChannel))
        {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            requestMessage.Headers[Static_Functions.OAuthHeader] = oAuthHeader;
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;

            CallContext callContext = new CallContext { Company = "DAT" };

            string empId = "000509";
            string pass = "test";

            #region Validate User

            SchindlerTechAssist.Droid.D365Service.PWBMobServiceValidateUserRequest validateUserRequest = new SchindlerTechAssist.Droid.D365Service.PWBMobServiceValidateUserRequest();
            validateUserRequest.EmployeeId = empId;
            validateUserRequest.Password = pass;

            SchindlerTechAssist.Droid.D365Service.MobilityService service = (SchindlerTechAssist.Droid.D365Service.MobilityService)dimServiceChannel;

            var resultAsync = service.BeginValidateUser(validateUserRequest, null, null);
            resultAsync.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

            var result = service.EndValidateUser(resultAsync);


            #endregion

        }
```

Comment: I'm seeing this exact issue. On our internal Dynamics 365 Finance And Operation Custom Web Service it's working. On our clients, I'm receiving the same error. Did you get past this?

Comment: Haven't got any response so far I'm afraid :-(
I switched to JSON and that's working just fine

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to enable TLS 1.2 in Android Properties. Dynamics Test/Production environments require TLS 1.2 from the client.